# VBA to reorder and repeat certain text columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following table of raw data:

> 1995 (1)
>   (23:00)
>
> Math 0630 
>   0830 Break 0930 
>   1000 English 1200 
>   1200 Lunch 1300 
>   1330 Free

I need to have it read like this:

> 1995 (1) (23:00) 0630 Math 0830 0930 Math Break 1000 1200 Break English 1200 1300 English Lunch 1300 1330 Lunch Free

Right now my Macro code has it reading like this:

> 1995 (1) (23:00) Math 0630 0830 Break 0930 1000 English 1200 1200 Lunch 1300 1330 Free

Here is my code:

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("D29").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select


'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(1, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(37, 1), _
        Array(42, 1), Array(58, 1), Array(63, 1), Array(79, 1), Array(84, 1), Array(100, 1), Array( _
        105, 1), Array(121, 1), Array(129, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Rows("1:6").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Dim lastRow&, g&
Dim findStr$

findStr = "Planning of"

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For g = lastRow To 1 Step -1 ' change this to 2 if you have headers
    If Cells(g, 1).Value = findStr Then
        'Range(Rows(i), Rows(i - 4)).Select
        Range(Rows(g), Rows(g - 4)).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next g

Dim arr() As Variant
Dim p As Integer, i&
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim t As Integer
Dim c As Long
Dim u As Long



Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set tws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
i = 1
With ws
Do Until i > 100000
    u = 0
    For c = 1 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'If c = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column And .Cells(i, c) <> "" Then
        ReDim arr(0) As Variant
        p = 0
        t = 0
            Do Until .Cells(i + p, c) = "" And t = 1
                If .Cells(i + p, c) = "" Then
                    t = 1

                Else
                    arr(UBound(arr)) = .Cells(i + p, c)
                    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
                End If
                p = p + 1
            Loop

        If p > u Then
            u = p

        End If
        If c = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column Then
            If .Cells(i + p, c).End(xlDown).Row > 100000 And .Cells(i + p, 1).End(xlDown).Row < 100000 Then
                i = .Cells(i + u, 1).End(xlDown).Row
            Else
                i = .Cells(i + p, c).End(xlDown).Row
            End If

        End If
        tws.Cells(tws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr

    Next c

Loop
End With
With tws
    .Rows(1).Delete
    For i = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Left(.Cells(i, 1), 4) <> Left(.Cells(i - 1, 1), 4) Then
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next i
End With

'
' Macro6 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1:M67").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Output").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Screenshot of Data:

[image: Screenshot of Data]

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of the raw table data before the macro runs? I can't figure out which data is where on the worksheet after the text to columns rips up the first column.

Comment: @SilentRevolution I've included a screen shot of it. I was not sure of a simpler way to do the text to columns other than to record a macro and do it manually.

Comment: Doing something while recording a macro and then looking at the code is the way to learn if you ask me. I'll take a look at the screenshot when you post it. You could use the `split` function if you have a constant delimiter (a separating character) like a `,` or `-` or any other character between your bits of data.

Comment: @silentrevolution I just added the screenshot. It took awhile to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that I found the original code difficult to work with and I could not get the data in the right place with the column to text part.  I therefore have written new code for your problem. This code will go through your data as you presented it on your screenshot and will output on a second sheet, for the code to run your workbook must have at least 2 sheets.

Instead of using text to columns I used `split` function, all your data is separated by a " " (space). I have taken into account the possibility of an activity consisting of more than 1 word. 
 After the split is performed on an item e.g. `1530 Practice Test 1800`, the number of array elements is checked, if the number is greater than 3 (0 to 2), the times are stripped from the array (they are always the first and last element), the rest of the elements are then joined, and the times re-added at position 0 and 2 leaving the activity in 1.

The output is now in one long continuous string per day as I assumed that that was your plan. If you want the data to be output with each item in a different cell, you can remove the marked code at the end.

```
Sub GetSchedules()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Dim DataWs As Worksheet, OutputWS As Worksheet
    Dim DataArray() As String, temp1 As String, temp2 As String, temp3 As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long
    Dim EmptyRows As Long, WorkingRow As Long, StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long, NextStartRow As Long, FinalRow As Long

    Set DataWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set OutputWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    StartRow = 1: l = 1: FinalRow = 1

    Do Until StartRow > FinalRow
        For i = 1 To DataWs.Cells(StartRow, DataWs.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            EmptyRows = 0
            WorkingRow = StartRow
            Do Until EmptyRows = 2
                If DataWs.Cells(WorkingRow, i) = Empty Then
                    EmptyRows = EmptyRows + 1
                End If
                WorkingRow = WorkingRow + 1
            Loop
            EndRow = WorkingRow - 2

            If WorkingRow > NextStartRow Then NextStartRow = WorkingRow

            If DataWs.Cells(DataWs.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row > FinalRow Then
                FinalRow = DataWs.Cells(DataWs.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
            End If

            m = 1
            For j = StartRow To EndRow
                DataArray() = Split(DataWs.Cells(j, i), " ")
                If UBound(DataArray) > 2 Then
                    temp1 = DataArray(0)
                    temp2 = DataArray(UBound(DataArray))
                    DataArray(0) = Empty
                    DataArray(UBound(DataArray)) = Empty
                    temp3 = Join(DataArray, " ")
                    ReDim DataArray(2)
                    DataArray(0) = temp1
                    DataArray(1) = temp3
                    DataArray(2) = temp2
                End If

                For k = 0 To UBound(DataArray)

                    OutputWS.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
                    If m < 4 Then
                        OutputWS.Cells(l, m).Value = DataArray(k)
                    ElseIf m < 7 Then
                        If IsNumeric(DataArray(k)) Then
                            OutputWS.Cells(l, m - 2).Value = DataArray(k)
                        Else
                            OutputWS.Cells(l, m + 1).Value = DataArray(k)
                            OutputWS.Cells(l, m + 4).Value = DataArray(k)
                            m = m + 1
                        End If
                    Else
                        If IsNumeric(DataArray(k)) And k = 0 Then
                            OutputWS.Cells(l, m - 1).Value = DataArray(k)
                        ElseIf IsNumeric(DataArray(k)) And k = 2 Then
                            OutputWS.Cells(l, m - 3).Value = DataArray(k)
                        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(DataArray(k)) Then
                            OutputWS.Cells(l, m + 1).Value = DataArray(k)
                            If Not UBound(DataArray) = 1 Then OutputWS.Cells(l, m + 4).Value = DataArray(k)
                            m = m + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                    m = m + 1
                Next k
            Next j
            OutputWS.Cells(l, m - 3).Value = OutputWS.Cells(l, m - 4)
            OutputWS.Cells(l, m - 4).Value = OutputWS.Cells(l, m - 7)
            l = l + 1
        Next i
        StartRow = NextStartRow
    Loop

    Dim ResultArray() As String

    'If you want every item in a different cell rather than one long continuous string,
    'remove the code from the next "With OutputWs" to the next "End With"
    With OutputWS
        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ReDim ResultArray(1 To .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
            For j = 1 To .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                ResultArray(j) = .Cells(i, j)
            Next j
            .Rows(i).ClearContents
            .Cells(i, 1) = Join(ResultArray, " ")
        Next i
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```